# CSHTML/RAZOR code highlighting in pygments

Tags: ruby, jekyll, pygments

I'm using `aspx-cs` to highlight CSHTML/RAZOR view file codes in Pygments. But it is not properly highlighting in HTML. I'musing the following syntax.

```
{% highlight aspx-cs %}

<h2>Kendo UI DatePicker</h2>

        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                .Name("datepicker")
                .Deferred()
        )

        @section scripts {
            @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
        }

{% endhighlight %}
```

Result HTML:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-6/getting-started

Can you please suggest proper highlighter for CSHTML/RAZOR?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've edited my question.